# Rails 4 model returns always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am going crazy with the following error. I have a User class and two of its attributes (birthday & created_at => datetime) returns always nil besides it has a value on the database.

I'm using devise to manage the authentication.

This is the db table:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  encrypted_password character varying(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  reset_password_token character varying(255),
  reset_password_sent_at timestamp without time zone,
  remember_created_at timestamp without time zone,
  sign_in_count integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  current_sign_in_at timestamp without time zone,
  last_sign_in_at timestamp without time zone,
  current_sign_in_ip character varying(255),
  last_sign_in_ip character varying(255),
  name character varying(255),
  lastname character varying(255),
  birthday timestamp without time zone,
  gender character varying(255),
  created_at timestamp without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone,
  authentication_token character varying(255),
  facebook_uid character varying(255),
  gplus_uid character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

and this is the model

```
#encoding: utf-8
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :user_benefits
  has_many :benefits, through: :user_benefits

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :gender, :inclusion => { :in => %w(m f)}
  validates :email, email_format: { message: "Email invalido" }

  before_save :ensure_authentication_token

  def ensure_authentication_token
    if authentication_token.blank?
      self.authentication_token = generate_authentication_token
    end
  end

  def set_gender new_gender

    case new_gender.downcase
      when "male"
        self.gender = 'm'
      when "female"
        self.gender = 'f'
      when "m"
        self.gender = 'm'
      when "f"
        self.gender = 'f'
      else
        self.gender = nil
    end

  end

  def get_response
    {
        :auth_token=>self.authentication_token,
        :user => {
          :email=> self.email,
          :name=> self.name,
          :lastname=> self.lastname,
          :birthday=> self.birthday,
          :gender=> self.gender,
          :auth_token=> self.authentication_token,
          :created_at=> self.created_at,
          :updated_at=> self.updated_at,
          :facebook_uid=> self.facebook_uid,
          :gplus_uid=> self.gplus_uid
        }
    }
  end

  private

  def generate_authentication_token
    loop do
      token = Devise.friendly_token
      break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
    end
  end

end
```

When I call get_response I'm getting:

```
{
  auth_token: "fRoi1RPTuP64m55jXCSS"
  user: {
    email: "testg@habitues.com"
    name: "Lalo"
    lastname: "Landa"
    birthday: null
    gender: "m"
    auth_token: "fRoi1RPTuP64m55jXCSS"
    created_at: null
    updated_at: "2013-11-27T20:14:22.534-03:00"
    facebook_uid: null
    gplus_uid: null
  }
  new: false
}
```

Someone has an idea?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.

Some days ago I changed the config/application.rb file adding the following configuration to solve some issues with timezones:

```
config.time_zone and config.active_record.default_timezone
```

I've just removed them and all is working fine again.

Answer (score 5):

`config.active_record.default_timezone` requires a symbol, either :local or :utc.

`config.time_zone` requires a regular time zone as you have done.

`config.active_record.default_timezone` determines whether to use Time.local (if set to :local) or Time.utc (if set to :utc) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is :utc.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, and it was specifically

```
config.active_record.default_timezone
```

This caused activerecord to return all UTC-stored timestamps as null. Not sure why, but removing it brought back all data. I was able to leave default config.time_zone in place.