# Rails 4. Undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass for created_at field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, strftime

Just a dead simple data recording app for recording & displaying timesheet entries in Rails 4. After realising that the recorded time entries are early by 2 hours for my timezone, I have set config.time_zone and config.active_record.default_timezone values to 'Berlin' respectively.

However, after this hack, ActiveRecord begins to add millisecond data to the 'created_at' sqlite-DB-column, which as a consequence throws the "undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass" error for my display of creation datetime.
This is how my ill view looks:

```
<table>
    <% @timesheets.each do |t| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= t.user.name %></td>
        <td><%= t.t_lines %> sor</td>
        <td><%= t.t_time %> perc</td>
        <td><%= t.created_at.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M') %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

Is there a way to stop rails recording precision time data, or another solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the record you're trying to print have its `created_at` column set in your DB?

Comment: Yes, it does, via Rails' migration auto timestamps.

Comment: Execute `def nil.strftime; end` at the beginning and the error will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a lot of research until finding the solution. I have also tried a full database reset without success.
Then I found this one:

[Rails 4 model returns always nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255272/rails-4-model-returns-always-nil)

The value of config.active_record.default_timezone in application.rb must not be set to a specific timezone, but to a symbol like :local or :utc.

```
application.rb:

config.time_zone = 'Berlin'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

This change and a further db:reset solves the problem.
Thanks for the contributions.

Answer (score 4):

```
t.created_at.try(:strftime,'%Y.%m.%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint aromero, this heals at least the error, however produces no output at all for the created_at field.

Comment: What would you expect in this case? The value is nil

Comment: This is what I expect, I do not understand however why a sophisticated framework puts nil values into the database, and why this feature cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional like this:

```
   <% if t.created_at.present? %>
        <td><%= t.created_at.strftime('%Y.%m.%d %H:%M') %></td>
    <% else %>
        <td><p> Time Not Available </p></td>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks K M Rakibul Islam, surely I could, but I would prefer to simply display a formatted 'created_at' value. :-)